# Template projects missing after updating to Unreal Engine 5.0.3

Tags: unreal-5

I just recently upgraded to Unreal Engine 5.0.3 and I cannot find different templates on the start window:

[image]

Previously there were many templates, like for a third person project, top-down, hand held etc. I was just starting to learn Unreal and they were pretty useful. How may I get them back? Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened to me also, I solved it by accessing the engine options using the arrow down button as shown in the following image:

[image: option menu]

From this menu I've selected the checkbox to add templates.  [image: template and functions]

Comment: this helped me a lot
molte grazie!